# how can i copy remote machine(linux machine) xml file to my local machine(windows machine) using tcl

Tags: tcl

i am using tcl script to change the password in a xml file and NYMEX server using expect `send` and `expect` commands.
so before doing that i want to copy linux machine xml file to my local windows machine then locally i want to change the password attribute value in that xml then put it back to linux machine.

is it possible through
`file copy {C:\Where\To\Copy\From.txt} {C:\Where\To\Copy.to}`

can i use `XCOPY` command in tcl? if yes please give some info.

can any1 please help me out...
thanks in advance.

Comment: Set up a Samba server on your Linux machine, make a share, mount it in Windows (you can automount it on startup) and access the file directly as e.g. L:\my.xml. Or copy it back and forth with `exec scp user@host:my.xml my.xml` and `exec scp my.xml user@host:my.xml`.

Comment: you don't need to mount it, just access it with `//machine/share/my.xml`

Comment: How do you plan to access the remote system? Telnet? SSH? SMB mounts? This changes how you go about doing this task.

Comment: @DonalFellows - i want using telnet.

Answer (score 1):

we can use putty to copy from linux machine to windows machine and vice-versa

extract putty in you machine. eg: `c:\putty`
move to `c:\putty` in CMD

run there to move linux to windows

```
pscp -l username -pw password ipaddressoflinuxmachine:/opt/TCagg/TCaggCombined/bin/fastfood/Clients/TA/abc.xml c:/temp
```

run there to move windows to linux

```
pscp -l username -pw password c:/temp/abc.xml ipaddressoflinuxmachine:/opt/TCagg/TCaggCombined/bin/fastfood/Clients/TA/
```